# goto-chg stops at undo branch point?

Tags: motion, undo-tree-mode

I'm using package [goto-chg](http://melpa.org/#/goto-chg) to move cursor to the last edit.  It works great most of the time, but it sometimes said "No further change info" even though there were more changes.  Using undo-tree's visualizer, I found that the problem usually occurs when there is a branch point.  Is there any way to fix it?  Or is there any better package?

Comment: Feel free to fix the package to work better with undo-tree.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with `undo-tree`.  At the time of this writing there is no workaround nor a fix on the horizon.  The last update to the package was [August 8, 2013](http://www.dr-qubit.org/undo-tree.html).  Apparently no one has a reliable way to even reproduce the problem.

To quote a [related SE post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/34214/15177):

> The author of undo-tree.el, Toby Cubitt, is presently too busy to fix
>   this particular bug. If he has time in the future, he may look into
>   the issue further. The author has indicated that he has difficulty
>   reproducing the error reliably, and was recently unable to reproduce
>   it using the master branch.
>
> -@lawlist

There are lots of suggested workarounds, none of which work in my experience.

There are several other packages [which are stated to have similar functionality](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GotoChg) to `goto-chg`.  These are:

- [goto-last-change.el](https://github.com/camdez/goto-last-change.el/blob/master/goto-last-change.el)
- session-jump-to-last-change in [session.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/session.el)
- [undo-browse.el](https://web.archive.org/web/20110907165255/http://www.gnufans.net:80/~deego/emacspub/lisp-mine/undo-browse/dev/undo-browse.el)

I have no experience with these and cannot vouch for them.

Comment: I tried goto-last-change.el and session.el, but they both have the bug at the undo branch point. undo-browse.el seems no longer maintained.. Thanks anyway!